# Solving Indefinite Integrals with U-Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

My book gave the following problem: $$\int\frac{\ln(x)}x \text{ dx} $$
It seems to be a simple u-substitution problem, but I had a slight difficulty:
I set $u=\ln(x)$. Then, I had $\int\frac{u}x \text{ dx} $ I took the derivative of ln($x$) which is $\frac1x$. Then, I got dx = $x$ du. If I plug this in, I still have an $x$ in my integral. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: No, if you plug $dx=xdu$ into your integral $\int\frac uxdx$ you'll get $\int udu$, so no $x$ left.

Comment: The $x$'s cancel each other out

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is: $$u = \ln(x) \Longrightarrow du = \dfrac{dx}{x}$$ So, when substituting:  $$\int \underbrace{\left( \ln(x)\right)}_{u} \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{dx}{x} \right) }_{du} = \int udu$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $du = \frac{dx}x$, so the integral becomes $$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \, dx = \int u \, du.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $u=\ln x$, then $e^u=x$. So $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ becomes $\frac u{e^u}$ and, since $x=e^u$, $\mathrm dx$ becomes $e^u\,\mathrm du$.

Don't forget: you have to do the substitution everywhere, not just at some places.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$t=\ln(x)$$ then $$dt=\frac{1}{x}dx$$ then we get $$\int tdt=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$$